# Spring logout gives 404 error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I've gone through all of the solutions listed at SO but can't seem to make it work. I've a simple spring-security xml file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd">
    <http auto-config='true' use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="user" password="user" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

My logout page looks like this-

```
<form action="j_spring_security_logout" method="post" id="logoutForm">
            <input type="hidden"
                    name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                    value="${_csrf.token}" />
</form>

<script>
    function formSubmit() {
                document.getElementById("logoutForm").submit();
    }
</script>

<c:if test="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name != null}">
           <h2>
                Welcome : ${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name} |
                 <a href="javascript:formSubmit()"> Logout</a>
            </h2>
</c:if>
```

But I get 404 error when I make HTTP POST; Spring gives following error message-

```
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/j_spring_security_logout] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-dispatcher'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Spring versions (from pom.xml)-

```
<spring-core-version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring-core-version>
<spring-security-version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring-security-version>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-logout), the logout URL ins Spring Security 4 is just `/logout`, so it should work if you change your form action.

I would also drop the `auto-config` attribute and just set what you want to use explicitly, following the examples in the manual.

Comment: I didn't drop auto-config, just used logout url to be /logout. Worked like a charm.